# How to parse any valid string to an integer using a specific radix?

Tags: java, android, parsing, integer, radix

### Background

Using [Integer.parseInt(someIntString, radix)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) doesn't always work and might return NumberFormatException on some cases.

I've checked the API and it says that such an exception will be returned :

> if string cannot be parsed as an integer value, or radix <
>   Character.MIN_RADIX || radix > Character.MAX_RADIX.

Sample code that causes the exception:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("ff00ff00",16));
```

On java I get the same exception.

Since an integer holds 4 bytes, this should still work, but it doesn't.

Here's a proof that such a thing is possible:

```
final String input="ff00ff00";
int output=0;
for(int i=0;i<input.length();++i)
  {
  output<<=4;
  final char c=input.charAt(i);
  if(c>='a')
    output+=c-'a'+10;
  else output+=c-'0';
  }
System.out.println(output);
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(output));
```

Note that I know of using the [Color.parseColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29) function (and it's probably very similar to the code I've written), but I want to handle any radix and not just hexadecimal.

I also know that using the parseInt supports negative values parsing, so that's why it probably causes the exception.

### The question

Is there a built in function or a know algorithm for parsing a string to an integer using any radix ?

I assume of course that the integer variable can hold the value (using max of 4 bytes ) and that the sign of the number is irrelevant .

Comment: @yoah Updated the question as it wasn't correct with its assumptions. Sorry.

Comment: ff00ff00 does not parse in Java either. 00ff00ff does, I think it is related to Java parsing a signed value so you can use "-123a". From what I see, Android does the same

Comment: @yoah I see. Is there a solution assuming that this will always be used for positive values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think there is no built in solution for this question, but it's quite easy to solve it using about the same code I've written in the question:

```
public static int parseInt(final String input,final int radix)
  {
  int output=0;
  for(int i=0;i<input.length();++i)
    {
    output*=radix;
    final char c=input.charAt(i);
    if(c>='a')
      output+=c-'a'+10;
    else output+=c-'0';
    }
  return output;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that java does not support unsigned integers, since "ff00ff00" is larger than a positive int could be, java counts it as out of range. A simple solution is to use Long.parseLong(string, radix), ideally you would change the type of the affected variables to longs, but you could make it work with some tricky casting too.

Comment: no matter. the solution I've written is probably good enough. using a larger-range variable-type isn't always possible (what would you do after long? use BigInteger?) . besides, you have to know when to use a different type, and for this you have to do extra calculations to know if it fits in the range or not.